# Counting frequencies of enum values

Tags: haskell, enums

Suppose I have an enum like

```
data T = A | B | C deriving (Enum)
```

and a list of enum values as input:

```
[B, C, C, A, C, A, C]
```

What I'm looking for is a function that, given this input, returns how often each element occurs in the input. A simple form for the output would be a list of the frequencies (`[2, 1, 4]` in this case), but this is not a requirement. My current approach looks like this:

```
countEnum :: Enum a => [a] -> [a] -> [Word]

countEnum elems =
  let f x = map (fromIntegral . fromEnum . (fromEnum x ==)) [0 .. length elems - 1]
  in foldr (zipWith (+)) (replicate (length elems) 0) . map f
```

This works, but I see at least two issues:

1. It uses the `length` function.
2. It requires that the caller specifies all possible values in the first argument.

Is there a way to improve this?

Comment: Is the type declaration wrong? Why does `countEnum` take two inputs?

Comment: @is7s: The first argument is a list containing all possible values (mostly to find out how many there are).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually a bit faster than sorting a list is using a `Map`,

```
enumFreq :: Enum a => [a] -> Map Int Word
enumFreq = foldl' (\mp e -> Map.insertWith' (+) (fromEnum e) 1 mp) Map.empty
```

and you can get

- the frequencies only per `Map.elems $ enumFreq list`
- the pairs `(value,frequency)` per `[(toEnum i, f) | (i,f) <- Map.assocs $ enumFreq list]`

If your type is itself in `Ord`, you can skip the `fromEnum` and `toEnum`.

If you have `Ix` and `Bounded` instances and the type doesn't have too many elements,

```
import Data.Array.Unboxed

enumFreq :: (Ix a, Bounded a) => [a] -> UArray a Word
enumFreq = accumArray (+) 0 (minBound,maxBound) . (`zip` repeat 1)
```

has better asymptotic behaviour, uses less memory and is faster already for fairly short lists. (But that depends on a high proportion of the type's elements being present in the list.)

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I need. Meanwhile I've found a similar solution based on `Map`, but yours is more concise.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe something like this?

```
import Control.Arrow ((&&&))
import Data.Function (on)
import Data.List (groupBy, sortBy)

data T = A | B | C deriving Enum

countEnum :: Enum a => [a] -> [Int]
countEnum = map length . groupBy ((==) `on` snd) . sortBy (compare `on` snd) . map (id &&& fromEnum)
```

For example:

```
> countEnum [B, C, C, A, C, A, C]
[2,1,4]
```

If you can define a `Bounded` instance for `T` then there is possibility to count zero occurrences:

```
countEnum' :: (Bounded a, Enum a) => [a] -> [Int]
countEnum' = map pred . countEnum . (++ enumFromTo minBound maxBound)

> countEnum' [C, C, A, C, A, C]
[2,0,4]
```

Comment: That looks really nice, however it doesn't work if not all of the possible elements actually occur in the input list (the corresponding element in the result list is left out, it should be zero).

Comment: @Philipp I don't think this is possible without `Bounded` instance or explicit argument as in your initial example.

Comment: `enumFromTo minBound maxBound` can be written as `[minBound .. maxBound]`

Answer (score 2):

If you have `Ord`, you can have key-value pairs by using

```
import Control.List
import Control.Arrow

map (head &&& length) $ group $ sort elems
```